# Infinite loop with for on files in directory(batch, cmd)

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, infinite

I have a specific problem, which I couldn't find.

There is a folder, inside which are **.txt files in cp866** encoding with the following structure:

```
directory
‐‐2004_lpq.txt
--2006_lpq_jargon.txt
--barlou.txt
```

I need to convert all **.txt files in utf-8** without changing file names and directory structure.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off

for /r %1 %%f in (*.txt) do (
    iconv -c -f cp866 -t utf-8  %%f > %%f.temp 
    echo converted %%f
    move %%f.temp %%f 
)
```

How I run the script:

```
converter.cmd directory
```

Output:

```
converted "E:\YandexDisk\Учеба\OS\CMDProblem\directory\2004_lpq.txt"
Moving files:         1.
converted "E:\YandexDisk\Учеба\OS\CMDProblem\directory\2006_lpq_jargon.txt"
Moving files:         1.
converted "E:\YandexDisk\Учеба\OS\CMDProblem\directory\barlou.txt"
Moving files:         1.
converted "E:\YandexDisk\Учеба\OS\CMDProblem\directory\2004_lpq.txt"
Moving files:         1.
converted "E:\YandexDisk\Учеба\OS\CMDProblem\directory\2006_lpq_jargon.txt"
........
```

On other machines it works fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: When the `.temp` file is moved and renamed to `.txt`, it is picked up again by the `*.txt` inside the `For` parentheses. You would be better off performing the `Move`s outside of the `For` loop.

Comment: I thought about that but it is correct working on other computers! It's a little strange.

Comment: Yes. This behavior depends on several details, including the type of the file system in each computer. The simplest solution is change your `for /r %1 %%f in (*.txt) do (` command by an equivalent `for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /S /A-D /B %1\*.txt') do (` one, in which the `dir` command is ejecuted just once before any file is processed...

Answer (score 0):

As Compo suggests, it is best to put the temp file outside the current directory. Also best to quote filenames in case they contain a special character such as a space.

```
for /r %1 %%f in (*.txt) do (
    iconv -c -f cp866 -t utf-8  "%%~f" > "%TEMP%\%%~f.temp"
    echo converted "%%~f"
    move "%TEMP%\%%~f.temp" "%%~f" 
)
```

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks very much :) It's so simple, but for some reason I did not think of it.